# Advanced formatting rules for StringBuilder.AppendFormat

Tags: c#, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I've seen on this [site](http://dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-1) a StringBuilder code sample illustrating `AppendFormat` usage:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static int[] _v = new int[]
    {
        1,
        4,
        6
    };

    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int v in _v)
        {
            b.AppendFormat("int: {0:0.0}{1}", v,
                Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
}
```

> ```
> === Output of the program ===
>
> int: 1.0
> int: 4.0
> int: 6.0
> ```

Where can I find documentation on those *advanced rules* for string formatting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)
- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [this](http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by checking the [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) article at MSDN. From there you will find links to standard format strings for [numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), as well as links to the custom format strings for both [numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).