# Data Format Error in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to set my Salary field value into $23,000.00 and send that value into my database ,i created below code inside my model class but it has some errors need some one help to fix that errors,I am new to Asp.net MVC4 Please help me to solve that problems.

when i save data it goes to database like that way- $23000
but actually i want to send like that way -$23,000.00

when i view my results in my view page it seems $$23000
But i want that way - $23,000.00

Please help me to solve that problems.

Thanks .

```
public string Salary
    {

        get
        {
            return SalaryFormat;
        }

        set
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            SalaryFormat = Convert.ToString(sb.AppendFormat("${0: #,###.00}", value));

             //SalaryFormat =   value;
        } 
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is data type of field named Salary?

Comment: you can see this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570370/advanced-formatting-rules-for-stringbuilder-appendformat

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! A `salary` being a numeric value should be properly stored as `decimal(15,2)` or something like that - but **definitely NOT** as `nvarchar` !!